# Is it possible to use a static analysis tool like FindBugs with Android?

Tags: android, static-analysis, findbugs

I am relatively new to Android development and a quick google search turned up nothing of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use directly findbugs, you need to fix new rules, but it's ok for everything else.